# Unexpected result from CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is putting content of "|" after each first level anchor tag "which is the main menu not the sub-menu" follow #menuCont but exclude the last child.
tried to do it with CSS then I had unexpected result, then tried with jQuery and I had another unexpected result.

**Main page menu HTML**

```
        <div id="menuCont">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="root/vision.html">Vision</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Mission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Values</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="root/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Activities</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Facilities</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Students</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**Another page menu HTML**

```
<div id="menuCont">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Static pages</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Homepage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Mission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Values</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="root/gallery.html">Dynamic pages</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Administration</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Create accounts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Edit accounts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Assign Students</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Assign teachers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS Controlers
    CSS approch**

```
#menuCont ul li a:after {content:"|"; font-size:30px; color:#FFF !important; font-weight:bold; color:#044c9e; margin:15px 5px;}
#menuCont ul li a:last-child:after {content:"" !important;}
```

**CSS Approch for jQuery**

```
#menuCont ul li a.conAfter:after {content:"|"; font-size:30px; color:#FFF !important; font-weight:bold; color:#044c9e; margin:15px 5px;}
```

**jQuery code**

```
$("#menuCont").children().children().children("a:not(:last-child)").addClass("conAfter")
```

**The unexpected results in reflect of the CSS approch:**

"Main page"

From Ie = it just selects all of the anchor tags and add the content to them and totally ignored where I ask to remove the content from last child.
From Ff,Gc,Sf,Op = I get the same from all of them, which is they select only first child and add the content to it.

"The other page"

From Ie = it just selects all of the anchor tags and add the content to them and totally ignored where I ask to remove the content from last child.
-This is different-From Ff,Gc,Sf,Op = I get the same from all of them, they add the content to all of the elements except the first anchor tag.

**The unexpected results in reflect of the jQuery approch:**

"Main page"

From Ie,Ff,Gc,Sf,Op = I get the same from all of them, which is they select only first child and add the content to it.

"The other page"

From Ie,Ff,Gc,Sf,Op = I get the same from all of them, they add the content to all of the elements except the first anchor tag.

Thanks all.

---

**Thanks to @charlietfl I managed to reach a neutral state.**

I will emphasis the solution in case somebody reaches that post with the same problem.

To get only the first level of children I need to use CSS child selector ">" start from the ancestor to the parent to the child if you get what I mean, that will give me an exact and specific selection.

And the other problem I didn’t notice that I’m calling the last child of the anchor tag instead of calling the anchor tag itself < a >, by calling the last child of < li > which is a, I got what I wanted.

Yet, IE8 didn’t understand that line, but all of the other browsers get it quiet good.
Good luck all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use `>` will denote children only

```css
#menuCont > ul > li >a:after {content:"|";padding:0 10px; color:red;font-weight:bold ; }
#menuCont > ul> li:last-child >a:after {content:"" !important;}
```

Also note looking for `<a>` of last child `<li>`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cWHhu/)

Comment: You are brilliant!!
Just to emphasis what you said:
By following the child selector from the ancestor I get a specific selection.
And I was selecting the last child of <a> instead of selecting the <a> itself.
Thank you allot.

Still IE8 ignores the 2nd line from the CSS, which strip the content, but I don't mind that actually, burned enough time.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

couple thing i see are the color is making the link invisible if you have a white background, but the underline needs text:decoration:none;

is this fiddle here what you are after?

http://jsfiddle.net/MV2dn/2/